# Unable to get Hijri date from the UIDatePicker in ios Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am not able to get the Hijri date format in objective c.I have used a UIDatePicker on which i have added below code for showing the date as hijri.

```
self.datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
self.datepicker.calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic];
```

I am getting picker as below[image]

But when i get the date from the UIdatePikcer i get date as 08/03/2017 but not as hijri date.

I am using below code to convert date into string.

```
-(NSString *)convertStringFromDate:(NSDate *)date 
{

  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

  NSLog(@"date is %@",date);
  NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
  return dateString;
}
```

Please tell me how i can solve this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

A `NSDate` object is a object that holds a date but does not know how to present it will be presented to a user. See it an universal way to store dates, it does not use AM/PM, 24 hours or Gregorian calendar.

When you print/log a `NSDate` object it will use the systems calendar to represent the date.

To format a `NSDate` you use `NSDateFormatter` which will transform the date to something a user will understand. But you will have to tell the `NSDateFormatter` how to format the date.

The part you forgot is to tell `NSDateFormatter` to use the `NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic` calendar.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
dateFormatter.calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];


NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"date is %@",dateString);
```

This gave me `date is 10/06/1438` for today's date ( 8 March 2017)